# How can be modified font weight in Beamer/LaTeX globally?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm trying to increase font weight in Beamer globally.

I tried to test with help of:
https://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/fntguide.pdf
and http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf

to change only bold default (only for testing purposes):

\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{[X]}

as [X] I've tried combinations from https://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/fntguide.pdf#page=5
but there was only two weights working bx and m.

How can I properly change font weight globally? Is it font problem (CMSS)?
Thanks.

Comment: most font families are only available on one or two weights

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose a (sans-serif) font family with multiple weights (as Source Sans
Pro).

Choose the weights for medium series and bold series from `el` (extralight), `l` (light), `m` (medium), `sb` (semibold), `b` (bold) and `eb` (black).

In my example, I choose `sb` and `eb`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\makeatletter
\def\mdseries@sf{sb} % el l m sb b eb
\def\bfseries@sf{eb} % el l m sb b eb
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \huge
  \begin{itemize}
  \item The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  \item \textbf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]